# How can I add a little green triangle at the bottom right of a table cell?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can I add a little green triangle at the bottom right of a table cell?

I tried it with this code snippet :

```
<td style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red 4%,white 1%)"></td>
```

However, that doesn't work as I want it to.
I need it exactly at the  at the bottom right of a table cell!

Comment: <td style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red 4%,white 1%)">

Comment: It's just `background`, not `background-image` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can make the green triangle appear only at the last column of every row :

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  outline: 2px solid #ccc;
}

td:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #9ACD32;
  border-right-color: #9ACD32;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 1, Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 2, Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 3, Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 3, Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vyb4zp82/))

---

Here's how you can make the green triangle appear only at the last column of the second row :

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  outline: 2px solid #ccc;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #9ACD32;
  border-right-color: #9ACD32;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 1, Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 2, Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3, Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 3, Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 3, Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vyb4zp82/1/))

Comment: how to give to any specific row ?

Comment: You could add `tr:nth-child(N)` to your selector, where `N` is the index of the row you're targeting. I updated my answer with a new demo!

Answer (score 2):

I did let a CSS triangle (made with borders) on `:after` with `position:absolute`

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: lavender;
}

td:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellowgreen;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>data content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rejyVb?editors=1100)